# VBA Code for search box that filters table

Tags: vba, excel

I've designed a search box that filters my table when text is entered into said search box. The problem is that it is soooo slow, it's almost not even worth having it in my workbook right now.

Can anyone think of any way to revise/improve upon this code?

Here is my code currently:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 Dim searchArea As Range, searchRow As Range, searchCell As Range
 Dim searchString As String
 Dim lastRow As Integer

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 searchString = "*" & LCase(TextBox1.Value) & "*"
 Rows.Hidden = False

 lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Set searchArea = Me.Range("f3:f791", "f3" & lastRow)
 searchArea.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 For Each searchRow In searchArea.Rows
   For Each searchCell In searchRow.Cells
     If LCase(searchCell) Like searchString Then
       searchRow.Hidden = False
       Exit For
     End If
   Next searchCell
 Next searchRow

 Application.Goto Range("Z1"), True
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Edited my code to this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("states").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:="*" & [G1] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

However, this is not working. There are text and numbers in Field 1, and this only is filtering text, not the numbers...

Comment: Consider using the `AutoFilter` method, rather than row-by-row/cell-by-cell iteration?

Comment: So what would that code look like? Sorry, still very new at VBA...

Comment: You're also iterating over a single column range, and introducing redundancy therefore, because you're doing `for each searchcell in searchrow.cells`.

Comment: I told you what method to use, now the idea is that you look up the documentation, or use the Macro Recorder to configure an AUtoFilter, and then we can assist you in modifying if needed :)

Comment: (a) `Me.Range("f3:f791", "f3" & lastRow)` <-- if lastRow is 602 (i.e. last populated cell in column A is $A$602), you are setting `searchArea` to be `$F$3:$F$3602` - this seems much bigger than you want it to be.  (b) The `TextBox1_Change` event will be being processed every time the user changes the value in the text box so, if they are searching for `xyz`, you will be performing your code with values of `x`, `xy`, and `xyz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely redundantly redundant, because your iteration is over a single column:

```
 For Each searchRow In searchArea.Rows
   For Each searchCell In searchRow.Cells  '### searchRow ONLY HAS ONE CELL! This second/inner loop is totally unnecessary
     If LCase(searchCell) Like searchString Then
       searchRow.Hidden = False
       Exit For
     End If
   Next searchCell
 Next searchRow
```

Rewrite as:

```
For Each searchCell in searchArea.Cells '## Assumes searchArea is single column
   searchCell.EntireRow.Hidden = Not (LCase(searchCell) Like searchString)
Next
```

That alone should improve performance, but I think `AutoFilter` is a better method, and you should be able to derive the basic code for that from the Macro Recorder.

This would look something like:

```
searchArea.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & searchString, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
```

This should filter to display only non-blank rows which contain your `searchString`

@Yowe3k's points about the range assigment should also be noted, and you may use the `AfterUpdate` event of the TextBox instead of the `Change` event.

**UPDATE** This might work to handle your mixed cases of numeric/text values. There might be a better way to do this but I don't see an obvious solution. The AutoFilter is meant to work with *either* text *or* numbers, but not both. So this attempts to convert numeric values to string representations.  You may need to make changes elsewhere if the numeric values are referenced in formula, etc.

```
Dim arr, v
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
' ## Disable filter if it's on already
If tbl.Range.AutoFilter Then tbl.Range.AutoFilter
arr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Value
' ## Convert your range of mixed numeric/string to string
For v = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If IsNumeric(arr(v, 1)) Then
        arr(v, 1) = "'" & CStr(arr(v, 1))
    End If
Next
' ## Put the string data back out to the worksheet
tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Value = arr
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
       Criteria1:="*" & CStr([G1]) & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thanks David. I updated my code, but am still having some issues with it.

Comment: Grammar police:  "you're iteration is over" --> "your iteration is over", or "you're iterating over"

Comment: @YowE3K hahahah you know what I was going back-and-forth between "your iteration is" and "you're iterating over" and apparently I confused myself, will fix :)

Comment: The grammar police will now go back to sleep until they are once again called upon to defend the city from ignorant (and forgetful) citizens

Comment: Spelling police:  "assigment" --> "assignment"

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks David.